# Rails: Could not find rake-10.1.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rake

I am experiencing an error with running the Rake command. When I try to Rake in my Rails project, I get an error that says `Could not find rake-10.1.1 in any of the sources`.

I put Rake 10.1.1 in my Gemfile, but it appears to do nothing when I bundle install.

I've tried uninstalling then installing the Rake gem in my computer's Ruby, RVM Ruby-2.1.0, the RVM Ruby-2.1.0@global, and the RVM gemset that I created for the specific project. I've also tried removing the Gemfile.lock and then bundle installing.

I've tried to manually run rake out of the terminal in multiple different Ruby/gems files including RVM. It gives this error:

`/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake ; exit;
~ me$ /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake ; exit;
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)`

I have a Rakefile in my project and have tried renaming it as well (Rakefile.rb, rakefile).

When I run Rake commands such as `rake db:migrate`, I get this error:

> rake aborted!
>   undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
>   /Users/me/RailsProject/config/environment.rb:4:in`'
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`block in require'
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`require'
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in`block in run_tasks_blocks'
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I've looked everywhere for the solution before coming here, but I could not find it. I would be appreciative if someone could give me some advice on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried "bundle exec rake db:migrate"

Comment: I get the same long error that I listed in the second block.

Comment: Is there some kind of system-wide command I can use to uninstall all references of a gem? Or reset/update a gem over the entire system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was, but I solved it by creating a new gemset, installing `Rake` to it, and using it. I also switched from Rubymine to Sublime. It may have been Rubymine trying to use a different gemset. Beware of those IDE settings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it it having trouble finding dependencies. Have you installed rake on your system with `gem install rake`?  If not you will need to use `bundle exec rake`.

Comment: 'gem install rake' does nothing in any of my Ruby/gem folders. It installs there, but I still get the same error when I try to Rake. And 'bundle exec rake' gives me the same error I listed in the second block.

Comment: What is on line 4 of your config/environment.rb file? Is RVM working everywhere else? For instance, if you create an empty rails project it does it boot up without error?

Comment: It's 'config.gem "declarative_authorization", :source => "http://gemcutter.org"'. But when I delete it, it does nothing different. Yes, RVM seems to be working perfectly find, aside from this. No, I cannot create an error free Rails project. I used to be able to, but it (Rake) stopped working.